# Flexbox infered dimensions inconsistency

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I'm trying to create an auto-sized flexbox with wrapped items organized in column, but the width don't match the box...

Here is the html body :

```
<body>
    <div id="flex">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my css file :

```
* {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#flex {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    background: green;
    height: 500px;
}

.item {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: red;
}
```

[image]

As you can see, #flex width is 80px, the width of an item...

Now, if I change a few properties to :

```
#flex {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

[image]

#flex height is growing properly! How could I achieve such behavior to width with items organized in column?

Comment: would you make it more clear? or show a pic of what exactly you need to get ? as i can't get your question yet ? how should the data be rendered ? in column case ?

Comment: I found out my question is a duplicate...
Flex items overflow their container in column mode, it's a common bug which has been there forever ^^'